# Grouping elements based on sec value using xslt 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt

I have elements in sequential order. I need to group the elements based on sec value. Below I mentioned my input.

```
    <body>
    <title>first</title>
    <entry><sec>s 2</sec><p><text>some text 1</text></p></entry>
    <entry><sec>s 3</sec><p><text>some text 2</text></p></entry>
    <section>section title</section>
<entry><sec>Sh 1</sec><p><text>some text 3</text></p></entry>
    <entry><sec>Sh 1<sub>Pt 2</sub></sec><p><text>some text 4</text></p></entry>
    <entry><sec>Sh 1<sub>item 1</sub></sec><p><text>some text 5</text></p></entry>
    <entry><sec>s 8</sec><p><text>some text 2</text></p></entry>
    <entry><sec>s 9</sec><p><text>some text 2</text></p></entry>
    <entry><sec>Sh 2<sub>item 2</sub></sec><p><text>some text 10</text></p></entry>
    <entry><sec>Sh 2</sec><p><text>some text 20</text></p></entry>
    </body>
```

I am expecting the below output.

```
 <body>
<title>first</title>
    <entry><sec>s 2</sec><p><text>some text 1</text></p></entry>
    <entry><sec>s 3</sec><p><text>some text 2</text></p></entry>
<section>section title</section>
    <group>
    <entry><sec>Sh 1</sec><p><text>some text 3</text></p></entry>
    <entry><sec>Sh 1<sub>Pt 2</sub></sec><p><text>some text 4</text></p></entry>
    <entry><sec>Sh 1<sub>item 1</sub></sec><p><text>some text 5</text></p></entry>
    </group>
    <entry><sec>s 8</sec><p><text>some text 2</text></p></entry>
    <entry><sec>s 9</sec><p><text>some text 2</text></p></entry>
    <group>
    <entry><sec>Sh 2<sub>item 2</sub></sec><p><text>some text 10</text></p></entry>
    <entry><sec>Sh 2</sec><p><text>some text 20</text></p></entry>
    </group>
    </body>
```

Please try to help me.

Comment: See any `xsl:for-each-group group-by` example, for instance in the spec at https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#grouping-examples and it should be easy.

Comment: I am not familiar in grouping, but I tried. I cant able to bring the correct output. Please help someone.

Comment: Take your time to read an example and to try to adapt it, then show us your effort if you really can't get it working.

Comment: Below was what I try
<xsl:template match="body">    
<xsl:for-each-group select="entry" group-by="sec/text()[1]">
<group><xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"></xsl:apply-templates></group>            
</xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
<xsl:template match="body">
    <body>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="entry" 
        group-adjacent="starts-with(sec, 'Sh ')">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
                <group>
                <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
                </group>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>  
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
    </body>
</xsl:template>
```

**Output**

```
    <body>
    <entry><sec>s 2</sec><p><text>some text 1</text></p></entry>
    <entry><sec>s 3</sec><p><text>some text 2</text></p></entry>
    <group>
    <entry><sec>Sh 1</sec><p><text>some text 3</text></p></entry>
    <entry><sec>Sh 1<sub>Pt 2</sub></sec><p><text>some text 4</text></p></entry>
    <entry><sec>Sh 1<sub>item 1</sub></sec><p><text>some text 5</text></p></entry>
    </group>
    <entry><sec>s 8</sec><p><text>some text 2</text></p></entry>
    <entry><sec>s 9</sec><p><text>some text 2</text></p></entry>
    <group>
    <entry><sec>Sh 2<sub>item 2</sub></sec><p><text>some text 10</text></p></entry>
    <entry><sec>Sh 2</sec><p><text>some text 20</text></p></entry>
    </group>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. But I need one change. The sec value may varies as s1, ss 5. All sec dont starts with Sh .Please try for another solution.

Comment: @Reegan, Than provide rule for grouping.

Comment: I have give the condition as group-adjacent="sec/text()[1]". But the empty sequence error was occurring. Any solution Please.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to wrap the items if there is only one item in a group then use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">


    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

     <xsl:template match="body"> 
       <xsl:copy>
                  <xsl:for-each-group select="entry" group-by="sec/text()[1]"> 
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="current-group()[2]">
                            <group>
                              <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>                                
                            </group>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:for-each-group>
       </xsl:copy>

       </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

http://xsltransform.net/pNmBy2c

Comment: Mostly I found it brings what I expected. But one rule is that if another elements followed or preceded by entry is not comming in the output.

Comment: Well, how variable can the input be? If you know there is some element before the `entry` elements then simply put an `<xsl:copy-of select="* except entry"/>` before the `xsl:for-each-group`.

Comment: Sorry. Still I never got the required output

Comment: Anyone please try.